# how to get "today's" quotes from yahoo via pandas-datareader

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

for using pandas-datareader with yahoo, when I have start and end as the same date I get no information returned when I ask on that date. If I ask a day later, it works. But I want today's close today.

```
import sys
from sqlalchemy import *
import os
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web

end = datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15)
start = datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 15)

path = 'c:\\python34\\myprojects\\msis\\' 
try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except:
    pass
fname = path + 'test.txt'
fhand = open(fname, 'w')

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:@localhost     /stockinfo')
connection = engine.connect()

result1 = engine.execute("select symbol from equities where daily = 'Y'")

for sqlrow in result1:
    try:
        info = web.DataReader(sqlrow[0], 'yahoo', start, end)
        print (info)
        close = info['Close'].ix['2015-10-14']
        print ("=========================" + str(round(close,4)))
        answer = "Closing price for " + sqlrow[0] + " is " + str(round(close,4)) + "\n"
    except:
        answer = "No success for " + sqlrow[0] + "\n"
    fhand.write(answer)
#   result2 = engine.execute("update holdings set lasrprice = " + round(close,4) + " where symbol = '" + sqlrow[0] + "'")
#   result2.close()

result1.close()
fhand.close()
```

The code takes the second "except" route.

What am I doing wrong/what is happening?

Comment: This is related to the yfinance API:  If you go to their website, you won't get a value for the requested date. http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL&a=09&b=15&c=2015&d=09&e=15&f=2015&g=d Also, there is a lag from the market close to when it is populated in their database.

Comment: The answer, by experimentation, appears to be to not ask for the info until AFTER 8:30 PM Eastern time.